# How to interpret data given from statistical software question?

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello I am trying to answer the following question. (Apologies for the image but it is perhaps clearer than me doing a table here).

[image]

I am quite stuck on a few points and wanted some help.

I think the distribution is a $t$ distribution with $6$ degrees of freedom. As we have $9$ countries recorded and $2$ things recorded so we get $9-(2+1)=6$.

For b) I know the formula that $\text{Estimate} ~\div~\text{Standard Error}=\text{t-value}$ so for the second column we can figure out the standard error is $1.415$.

Now for the top row I want to find the $t$ value corresponding to the $p$ value of $0.05$. So we want the number such that $95%$ of the distribution is less than the absolute value of that number.

So I think this gives $P(>|t|)=0.05$ so we look in the tables to find the value of $t$ that gives $0.025$ in the upper tail (since by symmetry the lower tail will contribute the other $0.025$).

This gives the value as $2.447$ and so the corresponding standard error is $6.0073$.

This is the main thing I am not too sure about so if anyone could help me out and explain if I am wrong what I should be doing differently that would be great.

Oh and for c) I said yes I would agree since $0.0003<0.01$.

Comment: your degrees of freedom are not correct: there are $7$ degrees of freedom (you are counting the intercept twice by evaluating $2+1$). you can check this easily by yourself, by computing the p-value with $6$ df and compare it with the one from the regression table. the mistake continues in the ongoing calculations. for b) your standard error should be 6.21663 with a t value of 2.364. besides the wrong $df$, I cant see a mistake.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help.